# How to add Junit tests outside src in intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

My project structure looks like this.

project/src

src contains Main.java

I am supposed to add tests as follows.
project/src
project/tests/test1.java

Comment: should be like this: ``src/main/Main.java``
``src/test/Test.java``

Comment: Do you use Maven in your project?

Comment: not outside src.

Comment: Create a directory names tests. Mark it as test sources root. Write your tests in this directory. Side note: if you're still not using packages, and you still think test1.java is a good name for a Java source file, start by learning the basics (packages, naming conventions, good meaningful naming)

Comment: You can perfectly adapt Donald Wus answer. Instead of `src/main/Main.java`, simply go with `project/src/Main.java` and it's test `project/test/MainTest.java`. The names themself are nothing else then names. Just make sure to configure the folders as source folders. (Using the naming `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` is some common best practice and convinience. But you are not forced to follow that)